# bulk update groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Any one have a groovy script or know a way to bulk updates the groovy scripts in the jenkins jobs?  I have post build - groovy scripts in all my jobs and need to update the scripts.  Since there are over 100 jobs, did not want to update it one by one.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run a groovy script in the console that updates the other jobs config.xml.